# How could I make sure that my mongo query uses indexes

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query

I am using `mongo-driver` mongo's official driver for Go. I have below index on the collection,

```
// 1
[
    {
        "v": NumberInt("2"),
        "key": {
            "_id": NumberInt("1")
        },
        "name": "_id_",
        "ns": "cgrates.cdrs"
    },
    {
        "v": NumberInt("2"),
        "key": {
            "setuptime": NumberInt("-1"),
            "account": NumberInt("1"),
            "runid": NumberInt("1")
        },
        "name": "setuptime_NumberInt(\"-1\")_account_NumberInt(\"1\")_runid_NumberInt(\"1\")",
        "ns": "cgrates.cdrs"
    }
]
```

And below is how my filter in golang code looks like.

```
filter := bson.M{"setuptime": bson.M{"$gt": startTime, "$lt": endTime}, "account": account, "runid": "*default", "originid": callId}
```

Since, i have composite index, so i wanted golang driver to send the query exactly in the same order i have put above.

But, since filter is a map, so golang does not give guarantee of it being intact. Eventually, i see my golang driver sending queries in out of order.

```
B....................K....update.....cdrs..lsid......id............A\.2.2......$db.....cgrates.......updates......q......account.....5ee919c63181373a24762676..runid.....*default..originid.%...161060e7-2a37-1239-7684-560001951c52..setuptime......$gt..)..r....$lt.....r......u......$set.#....extrafields.Paid.....0.00125....
```

Please check above query being sent to mongo, you might notice setuptime being at the last. While in filter it was the on first position.

How could I keep the query order intact or how to query based upon indexes? 
Does the mongodb handle this automatically?

Answer (score 1):

You can verify that indexes are used by using the [explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/) `mongo` shell method.

You can also provide the fields in different order in `mongo` shell and verify that the indexes are used.

Answer (score 0):

use bson.D, it will guarantee order

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/go/current/fundamentals/bson/